# Google Assistant Custom Commands in Mobile Application

Tags: google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

I've got an simple question: Is it possible to create customs commands with Google Assistant for specific actions in your own written mobile application?

Example actions such as:

- Navigate to that page
- call the helpdesk

In my research a found already IFTTT. With that you can create custom commands but i see only options as:

- Add new Google contact
- Turn on TV

but none specific actions for applications not written by Google. Is this even possible or you guys have any other ideas?

Thanks for Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now this is not possible. Eventually though, you will be able to use [App Actions](https://developer.android.com/guide/actions/) and [Slices](https://developer.android.com/guide/slices/) for that.

For that reason it's best to have a look at them and prepare your app for them.